# which way is the best way to initalize an array of strings?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

im trying to initilaize an array of strings which i will fill using a loop that asks for input from user, and im not sure which one of the three ways to use: (c programming)

- ```
  char *vocabulary[vocab_size] = {0}; //or NULL?
  ```
- ```
  char **vocabulary= {0}; // or NULL?
  ```
- ```
  char *vocabulary[] = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_LENGTH_OF_STRING*vocab_size);
  ```

the one comes most naturally to me is the first but according to our course using malloc is a good practice. mainly i have 3 questions:

1. which one is the best if im filling the array with input using scanf?
2. if its malloc is the format of right? because it is confusing using malloc for 2d arrays. and do i have to free it if im gonna need the array during the whole time im running the code?
3. if i initialize with a pointer that means its initialized with zeros, and pointers are stored in a part in the memory where changes cannot be done to the content of the array according to what i learned, will it still be possible to fill the array using scanf for each slot?

Comment: The first one allocates an array of pointers.  The 2nd one allocates a single pointer.  The last one allocates an an array of size `MAX_LENGTH_OF_STRING*vocab_size` but you assign it to an array of pointers which are two different things.  The answer is d. None of the above (at least if you want to allocate space for the strings themselves).

Comment: If vocab_size is small I would use the first then read your strings with `getline()` and just have it allocate each string for you.

Comment: @AllanWind i dont think i can use getline(), what can i use instead?

Comment: scanf() is fine just need to malloc each string then.  `vocab_size` has to be symbolic constant as you can't initialize a vla (re 1).

Answer (score 1):

Gotta run but this should get you started:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX_LENGTH_OF_STRING 42
#define str(s) str2(s)
#define str2(s) #s

int main() {
    size_t vocab_size = 3;
    char *vocabulary[vocab_size];
    for(size_t i = 0; i < vocab_size; i++) {
        vocabulary[i] = malloc(MAX_LENGTH_OF_STRING+1);
        scanf("%" str(MAX_LENGTH_OF_STRING) "s", vocabulary[i]);
    }
    for(size_t i = 0; i < vocab_size; i++) {
        printf("%zu: %s\n", i, vocabulary[i]);
        free(vocabulary[i]);
    }
}
```